# Accelerating hough transform algorithm in dm script using C++

Tags: c++, dm-script

Recently I tried to run Vincent Hou's Hough Transform script in https://www.felmi-zfe.at/dm_script/ for an image (1024*1024). The script take around 4mins on my computer. Then I tried to use the sampleInterface example in Gatan DMSDK to transform the dm script into C++ files and compile it into a DM plugin then tried to run it for the same image again. The time consumption was only reduced by 7s. I am not quite satisfied by this result. Then I looked at the generated code and found that the main part for the hough transform algorithm was still in dm-script. There was no C++ generated for that. Just some interface was generated.

Then I am trying to implement the dm script in C++. But I found it difficult to translate some features of dm-script into C++.

The first one is how to translate `imgHT[ HT_Col, y0 + tho_ratio*((iRow-y0)*sint+(iCol-x0)*cost) ] += source` into C++ code? I tried this:

```
for (uint32 iRow = 0; iRow < size; iRow++)
{
    for (uint32 iCol = 0; iCol < size; iCol++)
    {
        //imgHT[HT_Col, y0 + tho_ratio * ((iRow - y0) * sint + (iCol - x0) * cost)] += source;
    }
}
```

But there is no [] operator defined for Gatan::DM::Image class. So I made a comment to the code above.
So here are my questions:

1. Any suggestions for how to transform the commented line into a C++ code?
2. Is there a way in DMSDK to obtain data from Gatan::DM::Image class or transform this class to a 2D array (an array pointer to an array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually a DM-scripting question, but if you want to compute an image-array in the SDK you have to address the native, underlying number array (which is 1D and of a specific number type.)

Typical code for this is found in the SDK example, specifically in the `DMSDK\LibrarySuite\LibrarySuite.cpp` in the function `void PassRealImagePtr( DM_ImageToken image_token )`

One gets an image token passed in from which an image object is initialized. Then one creates a data-locker on the image to get access to a pointer to the native data array. The pointer needs to be cast into the appropriate number type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked and greatly reduced the running time, from original ~260s (dmscript) to ~3s. Before I tried GetPixel and SetPixel function in DMPluginStubs.h, but it will take even longer (~10000s) to finish the computation. Directly operating in the memory using image data-locker is the fastest way!

Comment: Yes, this is to be expected. The compiler will not be able to optimize around DM::... calls in the code. GetPixel() is worse than image-expressions (also in scripts) as it creates and release an image-access data-locker for each call.